# How to minify css using rollup plugin node-sass

Tags: sass, rollup, node-sass, rollupjs

I know that node-sass can minify css by default. But what option is there for a pipeline like mine, that creates a js and a separate css artifact?

```
const resolve = require('rollup-plugin-node-resolve');
const babel = require('rollup-plugin-babel');
const replace = require('rollup-plugin-replace'); // use to setup project enviroment variables
const sass = require('rollup-plugin-sass');
const json = require('rollup-plugin-json');
const image = require('rollup-plugin-image');
const reactSvg = require('rollup-plugin-react-svg');
const fs = require('fs');

const babelOptions = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('.babelrc'));

const js = {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: {
    file: 'lib/index.js',
    format: 'es',
  },
  plugins: [
    json(),
    reactSvg(),
    image(),
    sass({
      output: 'lib/styles.css',
    }),
    babel({
      ...babelOptions,
      babelrc: false,
      exclude: ['node_modules/**'],
      runtimeHelpers: true,
      comments: false,
    }),
    resolve({
      jsnext: true,
      module: true,
    }),
  ],
};

export default [js];
```

As you see, I only have an index.js file as input and output, but on the way I'm outputting the css separately. But how can I make that artifact being minified?

Or do you see any flaws in this kind of approach?

Answer (score 11):

You can actually use the `rollup-plugin-scss` plugin

```js
import scss from 'rollup-plugin-scss';
```

and set the option to minify using `outputStyle: "compressed"`

```js
// rollup.config.js

export default {
  //...,
  plugins: [
    //...,
    scss({
      output: 'lib/styles.css',
      outputStyle: "compressed",
    }),
    //...,
  ],
  //...,
}
```

to output a minified `.css` file.